# How Instagram inflate image color inside it background in Story Mode

Tags: android, image, instagram, background-color, edit

Hello since today I wonder how Instagram succeeded to introduce the most important color of the image in its background, I would like to add this kind of possibility in my application someone would know how I can do that? thanks for the help
[Here a image of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VVlC.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/palette-colors

Should work for you, implementation is easy

Comment: Hi sir thanks you for your answer , I just have a question how can I use that for convert image + background into a new PNG image ? (Sorry I'm a Beginner )